# Buying/selling options to have arbitrage

Tags: probability, finance

At time $t = 0$, a stock sells for $75$. At time $t = 1$, the stock will sell for either $50$, $75$, or $100$. You can purchase (or sell) the following two options:

(1) An option to buy the stock at time $t = 1$ for $50$;

(2) An option to buy the stock at time $t = 1$ for $60$.

The price of the first option is $10$. The price of the second option is $5$.

Give an example of a set of buy/sell decisions for the two options that guarantees a profit. (Note: only buy/sell the options, not allowed to buy/sell the stock.)

**My attempt:** Assume we buy/sell $x$ options $1$ for $10x$, and buy/sell $y$ option $2$ for $5y$. The total value at t=1 of ALL two options is: $0$ if price $= 50$ at $t=1$, $25x+15y$ if price $= 75$ at $t = 1$, and $50x+ 40y$ if price $= 100$ at $t=1$. Now, we need to choose $x$ and $y$ so that $25x+15y = 50x+40y$, which implies $y = -x$.

Thus, the final profit $ = 10x - (10x+5y) = 5x$ if price $=75$ or $100$ at $t=1$, and $= -5x$ if price $=50.$ This means $x$ needs to be simultaneously positive and negative, which is impossible. So no arbitrage??

**My question:** For the case when we sell the option, do we need to worry about "having to buy it" in case the option holder exercises the option? Otherwise, just sell $2$ call options and we're done?

Comment: that is the basis of an option you are hoping the market goes the way you want so that you keep the premium but if you have to make good on the option then you you buy the stock (or whatever) for the market price and then sell to the buyer of your option at the cost you wrote in the option - so you only hope the premium coveted the costs in that case I.e the valuation was sound.

Comment: @Chinny84: I meant, in the context of this problem, we are not allowed to buy/sell the stock. So, what is the example that gives us an arbitrage? And I was wondering whether the problem counts the case when we sell the option, the option was exercised and we HAVE TO buy the stock at overprice to pay back to the option holder. If this is indeed the case, my setup above for the final profit function is still valid I think, but why it gives me 2 contradictory cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you sell $3$ options with a strike price of $50$ and buy $5$ options with a strike price of $60$, or some multiple of this

You will receive a net premium of $3\times 10-5 \times 5=5$

- If the price at $t=1$ is $50$ then both types of options become worthless
- If the price at $t=1$ is $75$ then all the options are exercised and are worth to you a net $5 \times (75-60) - 3 \times (75-50)=0$
- If the price at $t=1$ is $100$ then all the options are exercised and are worth to you a net $5 \times (100-60) - 3 \times (100-50)=50$

So whatever happens you both get the premium of $5$ and have options worth $0$ or $50$, for an overall profit of $5$ or $55$ (plus any interest on the premium)

You would lose money if there were no interest and the price at time $t=1$ were between $51.67$ and $72.50$, but the question suggests this is not possible

Your error seems to be in trying to have the same profit with final prices of $75$ and $100$; meanwhile just selling two call options will lose money if the final price is $75$ or $100$ as the options will be exercised

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I think selling 4 options 1 and 7 options 2 also work? Could you help check? I adjusted my final profit function, which ends up with solving 3 inequalities: $-10x-5y > 0$, $15x+ 10y > 0$, and $40x+ 35y > 0$.

Comment: Anything strictly between the ratios $-1:2$ and $-2:3$ would work. Your $-4:7$ is in this interval, as is my $-3:5$

Comment: thank you for your help. Could you kindly help me review my solution to the following problem? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2041129/probability-of-funds-price-following-geometric-brownian-motion